# Putting values in mysql with previous value has same

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have:

```
mysql_query (sprintf ("UPDATE p_players SET badge = '<img title=Won-Server src=myn/img/badges/wonsmall.png>' WHERE id = %s", $this->data["id"]));
```

What I wanted is when I update again the same I don't want it to be replaced but I want the image display double.

Answer (score 0):

`... SET badge = CONCAT(badge, '<img ....>') ...`?

Comment: Spoon feeding won't get you anywhere @Nandan

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql_query (sprintf ("UPDATE p_players SET badge = CONCAT(badge, '<img title=Won-Server src=myn/img/badges/wonsmall.png>') WHERE id = %s", $this->data["id"]));
```